# How to redirect to a specific page without using the full URL

Tags: asp.net

I got a website published to server under `192.168.2.3`.
I want access to the login page without including the full URL, I want it to be done by just entering URL `192.168.2.3`, then after processing it become `192.168.2.3/login.aspx`.

The problem I currently encounter is that it always goes to `default.aspx`.

I had tried to add some code at `web.config` and it just came out as the error shown below.
[image]

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings />
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CompWebConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=TDSPWEBSVR\SQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=CompWeb;User ID=sa;Password=tdspp@ssw0rd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="TechnicianProgram/login.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your site in IIS one feature is Default Document. Check what has been set there. You may want to remove everything but the required login page path which will enable IIS to return the login page if the request URL does not specify a specific path.

This setting will update your web.config file with the values something like below-

```
<location path="folder1">
 <system.webServer> 
   <defaultDocument enabled="true">
     <files> 
      <add value="login.aspx"/> 
     </files> 
   </defaultDocument> 
 </system.webServer> 
</location>
```

[image]